# How to timestamp request logs with millisecond accuracy in Apache 2.0

Tags: apache, timing

How do I configure Apache 2.0's log format so that it timestamps each request log with millisecond (or microsecond) accuracy? The [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/logs.html) say that timestamps are specified in strftime format and strftime doesn't seem to handle anyting smaller than seconds.

Comment: How can anything more refined that a second be useful an any way, especially when it takes 100ms easily for something to spit across the net.  This just seems a touch obsessive.

Comment: 100ms is less than one second, TravisO.  I'm currently working on a load throttling system that requires millisecond accuracy.

Comment: This has been asked again and answered here on stackoverflow:
[Increase precission of apache log to include milliseconds][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405719/increase-precission-of-apache-log-to-include-milliseconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible (without rewriting APR, atleast). Apache uses [apr_strftime](https://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/2.0/group__apr__time.html#ga3f5e1aa45e735f3bcf8c13fb718c214f). On Unix, this calls the C library's strftime, but doesn't even fill milliseconds into struct tm (not surprisingly, because this structure doesn't usually support milliseconds in the first place). The Windows versions isn't much different.

Comment: %D   The time taken to serve the request, in microseconds.

Comment: As MikeT already pointed out, you _can_ get this on Apache 2.4, if you use %{msec_frac}t in your CustomLog format: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats

Apache 2.2 (not to mention 2.0) users are left in the cold.

Answer (score -1):

use %D option for microsecond accuracy

Comment: That measures the time taken to process each request, and not the timestamp for each request.