# Increase precision of apache log to include milliseconds

Tags: apache, timestamp, syslog, rsyslog

I have modified the configuration of `rsyslogd` to disable `RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat`.
But still the apache log `/var/log/apache/error.log` is displaying only second-precission.

Is there something else that needs to be configured?

Comment: Shouldn't be this question asked at ServerFault?

Comment: mmm, you are probably right, but the tags are there!

Comment: how can I move this to ServerFault?

Comment: This is old, but I would like to point out something that is still valid today. I came across this question and an equivalent one at ServerFault (https://serverfault.com/questions/589768/is-there-a-way-to-log-apaches-request-time-in-milliseconds). Here, the question is said to belong to ServerFault (and I tend to agree). On Serverfault however, the equivalent question was closed because deemed off-topic (totally ridiculous!). Also, people tend to prefer SO because SF is not as much populated, so it gives lower chances of reply. I see this all the time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html
you see differemt time formats including mili seconds
Just change from

```
%t 
to 
%{%d/%b/%Y:%T}t-%{msec_frac}t for miliseconds
or
%{%d/%b/%Y:%T}t-%{usec_frac}t for microsecs
```

Example:
16/Mar/2013:22:44:34-634
16/Mar/2013:22:44:34-634200

**Documenation apache**

> %t    Time the request was received, in the format [18/Sep/2011:19:18:28 -0400]. The last number indicates the timezone offset from GMT
>
> %{format}t    The time, in the form given by format, which should be in an extended strftime(3) format (potentially localized). If the format starts with begin: (default) the time is taken at the beginning of the request processing. If it starts with end: it is the time when the log entry gets written, close to the end of the request processing. In addition to the formats supported by strftime(3), the following format tokens are supported:
>
> sec         number of seconds since the Epoch
>
> msec    number of milliseconds since the Epoch
>
> usec    number of microseconds since the Epoch
>
> msec_frac   millisecond fraction
>
> usec_frac   microsecond fraction
>
> These tokens can not be combined with each other or strftime(3) formatting in the same format string. You can use multiple %{format}t tokens instead.

**strftime(3) formatting**
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html

Comment: Just a note - this doesn't work on 2.2 but only on apache 2.4+

Comment: Seems does not work in apache 2.4.10:
ErrorLogFormat "%{%d/%b/%Y:%T}t-%{msec_frac}t [%-m:%l] [pid %P:tid %T] [client\ %a] %M% ,\ referer\ %{Referer}i"
Output:
Fri Feb 20 16:32:18 2015-2015-02-20 16:32:18 [core:notice] [pid 2162:tid 140307424573312] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'